# An equivalence for unconditionally convergent series

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

I want to prove that in a Banach space $X$ a series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_{n} $$ is unconditionally convergent iif the set $A=\lbrace \sum_{i\in \sigma} x_{i}\hspace{2mm} : \hspace{1mm} \sigma \subset \mathbb{N} \hspace{1mm} \text{finite} \rbrace$ is relatively compact.

I have proved the implication $\Rightarrow $ using that relatively compact is equivalent to precompact (totally bounded set) in this case but I am not able to do the other one. Any help will be extremely grateful.